# Android how to select an invisible spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I am having trouble getting around a problem. In my application i have a spinner where a user selects a answer and then that answer gets passed onto the next activity. However, what i really want is the id of that answer to get passed on that activity...maybe seeing the code will help...

```
db = dbs.getReadableDatabase();     
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM answer table"; 
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SQL, null); 
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    final int l = cursor.getCount();
    int j = l + 1;
    array_spinner = new String[j];
    invisible_array_spinner = new String[j];
    int i = 1;
    array_spinner[0] = "Please select from below";
    invisible_array_spinner[0] = "Please select from below";
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     array_spinner[i]= cursor.getString(2);
     invisible_array_spinner[i]= cursor.getString(1);
     i ++;
    }
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in the answer table there is id and then answer, id is at cursor 1 and answer is at cursor 2.. What i am trying here to have maybe an invisible spinner in the back which reflects what the user has selected in the real spinner...Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?thanks

Comment: Im trying to save myself running another query, because the other option would be to run another query and find id where answer = the selected answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ahve to implement fol. code:

---

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

---

```
    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext()), "The planet is " +
              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
cnt=pos;//declare public variable cnt abve oncreate
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

---

after impl.it you get pos of selected itam of spinner in cnt var.

---

so you can get id for same spinner by

---

```
int id=invisible_array_spinner[cnt];
```